# Acrobat Adobe Writer

Tags: adobe-acrobat

What is Acrobat Adobe writer?  It is part of Adobe Acrobat?

If I have Adobe Acrobat, do I have the Writer?

Answer (score 0):

The correct terminology is that Adobe Acrobat is the program used to create PDFs, and the program that can only read them is Adobe Acrobat Reader.

People are pretty loose about the usage, though, and I'm always having to clarify with the users I support whether their question is about Acrobat or Acrobat Reader.  For some reason, although everyone uses the terminology "writing a PDF" I haven't heard too many people refer to the product as "Acrobat Writer."

Oh, and this probably belongs on superuser...

Comment: Ward, I was talking to somebody at my work and he said he needs Acrobat Adobe writer so the exact term is Acrobat Adobe.

Thanks a lot

Comment: The completely correct term is Adobe Acrobat - the company name (Adobe) goes first, then the product (Acrobat).

Answer (score 0):

I think the term you're looking for is "Acrobat Distiller". This is the program that will create a PDF from various sources (word, .ps file, etc)

The Adobe Acrobat you've referring to is most likely the Adobe Acrobat Reader - which is just a reader, and cannot be used to create PDFs.

The full Adobe Acrobat suite is very expensive ($900 last time I checked, which was about 5 years ago).

That said, if you need to create PDFs, Acrobat Distiller is no longer your only choice. Have a look on http://www.superuser.com - there's bound to be plenty of questions on there about creating PDFs.

Comment: Bullzip PDF Printer is my choice here but the most popular seems to be PDFCreator (http://alternativeto.net/software/pdfcreator/)